# How to drag and drop between two separate angular components (not under the same parent)?

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular7, angular-cdk

i'm new to angular and i need to drag and drop between two components (sidebar component and another component) .
I tried to use CDK drag and drop but **cdkDropListConnectedTo** and **cdkDropListGrou**p works only if the two components have the same parent (which is not the case) !!
[the two components that i want to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOp17.png)

Comment: Have you tried making a service that sets/gets the reference of each element to bind to the cdkDropListConnectedTo property? You'll probably find that if you're just trying [cdkDropListConnectedTo]=[myElementRef] then myElementRef is actually undefined as unrelated componenets won't have visibility of eachother.

Comment: Yes i did but it didn't work . Do you have an example maybe i'm missing something

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't tested it, it's just a suggestion for an approach.

Comment: thanks , i approciated .